# How to add txt files together and then remove duplicates

Tags: csv, command-line, duplicates

I have data in the form

file1:

```
rsID   score   score2
rs145  1.4     0.67
rs561  0.45    1.23
rs607  1.98    0.12
```

file2:

```
rsID   score   score2
rs561  0.45    1.23
rs234  1.74    0.22
rs256  1.09    0.34
```

file3:

```
   rsID   score   score2
   rs234   1.74   0.22
   rs109   1.44   0.80
   rs780   0.45   0.91
```

file4:

```
   rsID   score   score2
   rs234  1.74    0.22
   rs500  0.56    0.67
   rs614  0.81    0.50
```

I would like to add all of them together to get (just adding one to the bottom of the other, but removing all the duplicated rows):

```
   rsID   score   score2
   rs145  1.4     0.67
   rs561  0.45    1.23
   rs607  1.98    0.12
   rs234  1.74    0.22
   rs256  1.09    0.34
   rs109  1.44    0.80
   rs780  0.45    0.91
   rs500  0.56    0.67
   rs614  0.81    0.50
```

I have been successful in adding the files together with cat data.* > data.full. I still need to remove the duplicates though

Comment: read man uniq and look at sort -u

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer myself.

To add the data together I used `cat data.* > data.full`
This worked because all my data was saved as data.file1, data.file2, data.fil3, etc.

Then I got rid of the duplicates with `sort -u data.full > data.sorted.full` which only keeps unique data. I think it worked!